# Zero is valid in primary key

Tags: mysql

By default primary key field start from 1.
if i change it and add zero(0) id to my primary key field is valid and no problem?
or there's a standard for this issue?

the primary key type is "int(11)".

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html check the lower and upper limit for both signed and unsigned, for unsigned its from 0 to  4294967295

Comment: if you don't get error messages, it's valid...

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. Typically integers are signed, using negative ones would also be perfectly fine as far as the UNIQUE constraint is concerned. But for obvious reasons the convention is to start at 1 and go up.

See http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,230892,264799 :

> The default behavior is to create Signed integers.

Comment: Thanks, but usually professional programmer, use zero id ? (absolutely for exception table not all table)